# How to do set up for xamarin uitest for visual studio

Tags: mobile, automation, xamarin.android

How to install xamarin for testing the application built on Android studio.I want write the tests in visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the scripts on the application developed on Android studio, you just need to add following NuGet packages.

1. NUnit Framework.
2. NUnit Test Adapter.
3. Xamarin.uitest
4. Xamarin.uitest.helpers.